# ¿Cómo instalar una versión en concreto de una libreria en R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy intentando hacer una regresión logistica con la libreria caret. Para poder instalarla, me pide tener previamente instalada, la versión 1.0.5 de la libreria ggplot2. Parece que no me sirve una versión anterior. ¿Cómo puedo instalar una versión concreta de una librería en R?

Comment: La versión 1.0.5 es antiquísima, actualmente `ggplot` anda por l versión 3.3 y superiores. Más allá que podamos responder tu pregunta, me parece que el problema es otro, ¿podrías copiar a tu pregunta el código exacto del error?

Comment: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.3 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
6.
stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
5.
value[[3L]](cond)
4.
tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
3.
tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
2.
tryCatch({
attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only) ...
1.
library(ggplot2)

Comment: He probado también con los siguientes comandos: R.version

update.packages("ggplot2")

library(ggplot2)

Comment: Warning: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 4.2.2Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.3 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required parece que tengo que actualizar R...

Comment: Ok, el problema es que tienes una versión vieja de `rlang`  actualízala con `install.packages("rlang")` y si se instalo bien, vuelve a probar tu código, debería haberse solucionado el problema

Comment: Tengo la versi´n 4.2.1. de R, y necesito la 4.2.2. Estoy actualizando R, y las librerías con los siguientes comandos: El sofware R se puede actualizar fácilmente con el paquete installr, utilizar los siguientes comandos.

install.packages("installr", dependencies = TRUE)
library(installr)
updateR()

Comment: He instalado R, R Studio y los paquetes rlang y ggplot2 y sigue sin actualizarse. Ahora estoy probando a actualizar también Rtools que sirve para compilar paquetes desde el código fuente, y por lo que veo lo tenía también desactualizado.

Comment: En R studio tienes la posibilidad de actulizar todos los paquetes: `Tools > Check for packages updates`

Comment: Definitivamente, he tenido que actualizar R, R Studio y Rtools previo a la actualización de las librerías. Ahora ya funciona. merci.